# How to identify DF11 messages in AST48 field data

Tags: aircraft-systems

I have the radar output (Asterix) data.

How to identify the interrogator code sent by aircraft transponder in all call reply

Comment: [Eurocontrol Asterix Cat 048 specs](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/2022-12/eurocontrol-cat048-pt4-ed131.pdf).